# Perl regexes from a file -- how to use $1?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a list of regexes that I run on a string to convert it from one style of formatting to another.  For now, all of these regexes are stored in a file.

Usually, this works fine.  If it reads "Frog" into $from, and "Toad" into $to, then "$string =~ s/$from/$to/" changes all frogs into toads, as desired.

Now I want to do something trickier: given a date "2015-04-15", I want to to change it to "04/2015", again reading from a file.  If I load "(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)" into $from and "$2/$1" into $to, this doesn't work: it replaces the dates with the literal string "$2/$1", with actual dollar signs in the output.  What's do I need to do?

This is a script for home use only.  I am happy to use eval{} or any other strange thing if it will make my life simpler.

Comment: I would only like to add that `(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)` does not look fine to me, I'd rather use `(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
my $from = '(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)';
my $to = '"$2/$1"';
my $string = '2015-04-15';
$string =~ s/$from/$to/ee;
```

The above is short for the following:

```
my $from = '(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)';
my $to = '"$2/$1"';
my $string = '2015-04-15';
$string =~ s/$from/ eval($to) /e;
```

I prefer the second to the first since it doesn't hide the fact that [`eval(EXPR)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) is used. However, both of the above silence errors, so the following would be better:

```
my $from = '(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)';
my $to = '"$2/$1"';
my $string = '2015-04-15';
$string =~ s/$from/ my $r = eval($to); die $@ if $@; $r /e;
```

But as you can see, all of the above allow for the execution of arbitrary Perl code. The following would be far safer:

```
use String::Substitution qw( gsub_modify );

my $from = '(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)';
my $to = '$2/$1';
my $string = '2015-04-15';
gsub_modify($string, $from, $to);
```

Comment: And I prefer `\d{n}` :)  but well said

Comment: @vol7ron, That's not my code. If you have a style comment for the OP, tell it to him, not me.

Comment: Nah, I rather not bloat the answers since you and Choroba have covered the major point.  Instead, I would like to point out to you that preference is subjective and what matters is the objective qualities of your preference.  E.g. `I prefer the second to the first since ...` to `The benefit of the second over the first is that ...`  PCBP is less about preference and more about cost/benefit.

Comment: @vol7ron, I meant you should move the "I prefer `\d{n}`" comment to the Question since it has nothing to do with me or my answer.

Comment: @vol7ron, Not everyone sees a benefit in using `s/ /eval(EXPR)/e` over `s/ /EXPR/ee` as a benefit. "Preference" is therefore appropriate.

Comment: The mentioning of a preference in an answer is the point that I was making.  Preferences are debatable.  `eval(EXPR)` isn't the benefit, but you listed the benefit:  `it doesn't hide the fact that eval(EXPR) is used`.  It's phrasing and semantics is all I was getting at.

Comment: @vol7ron, What's PCBP?

Comment: PCBP: Perl Coding Best Practice

Comment: @vol7ron, And I repeat. I've encoutered many that don't see that as a benefit.

Comment: It is a benefit, but there are also benefits in not doing so.  The fact that it's your preference is less important than the fact as to *why* it's your preference.

Comment: I fully agree the why is the important part.

Answer (score 3):

To evaluate the replacement in a substitution, use the `/ee` modifier. This executes the replacement expression (`$to`) as Perl code and passes its result (the value of `$to`) to `eval EXPR`. As such, `$to` needs to contain valid Perl code, which means you have to quote the expression to avoid having it evaluated as division.

```
my $in = '2015-04-15';
my $expected = '04/2015';

my $from = '(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)';
my $to = '"$2/$1"';

$in =~ s/$from/$to/ee;
print $in eq $expected ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```